# If an element is non-zero, add a matching rows values

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

This one is breaking my brain:

I have a data.frame (or matrix if need be) of individuals (A-D) that have fought one another. Winners are on rows and losers in columns in a matrix. I need to calculate (for each winner), how many times their losers won other battles:

```
 | A | B | C | D 
A| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1
B| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0
C| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
D| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
```

So I would like to create variable L (loser wins) such that for each individual, if he/she beat an another individual, their row is summed and added to a total. In this example, the new variable would look like this:

```
 | A | B | C | D | L
A| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 (1 win from C, 2 from D)
B| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 (2 wins from A, 1 from C)
C| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 (2 wins from D)
D| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 (2 wins from B, 1 from D)
```

I have tried a *for* loop and have managed to get rowSums for each individual using:

```
l=c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
l[i]=rowSums(df[i,])
}
loserwinners=data.frame(l,row.names=rownames(df))
```

I know, gold star, whoopee. But I don't know the logical statement to call within a matrix if a value is non-zero, match that column name to the row name and add that row's values to a total. I would appreciate any leads on how to do this, and apologies if the syntax is incorrect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work I think. Loop across the rows with `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`. In each row, identify the columns that are greater than 0, and store the names. Then sum all of the values for the row(s) that correspond to each column name.

```
fights <- matrix(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                   0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                   0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
                 nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
rownames(fights) <- colnames(fights) <- LETTERS[1:4]

L <- apply(fights, 1, function(x) {
  who_lost <- names(which(x > 0))
  sum(fights[who_lost, ])
})

cbind(fights, L)

##   A B C D L
## A 0 0 1 1 3
## B 1 0 1 0 3
## C 0 0 0 1 2
## D 0 1 1 0 3
```

**Edit:** To expand on my comment below, *if your rows and columns are in the
same order*, the `names(which())` is redundant:

```
L <- apply(fights, 1, function(x) {
  who_lost <- x > 0
  sum(fights[who_lost, ])
})

cbind(fights, L)

##   A B C D L
## A 0 0 1 1 3
## B 1 0 1 0 3
## C 0 0 0 1 2
## D 0 1 1 0 3
```

Comment: Andy, thanks so much that worked perfectly, and is really a brilliant little piece of code. I am angry it took you so little time on something I had been working on for a few days! Nice one!

Comment: Glad it helped! Really learning to understand the *apply family of functions was one of the things that gave me the greatest leaps in using R more efficiently. NB: for this example, if your matrix is square and your rows and columns are always in the same order you could probably omit the names() function (and for that matter, now that I think more about it, the which() function as well). But using names is safer I think.